# strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior

Tags: php

Me salta este error en esta linea, reemplace el **strpos** por el **chr()** pero aun me seguia dando el mismo error a la hora de consultar, los logs que me arroja son estos

logs:

```
PHP Deprecated:  strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior in C:\wamp\www\include\web\sub\betado_stats.php on line 146
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\include\web\sub\betado_stats.php:0
PHP   2. strpos($haystack = 'Test e-Sports - Pug #1', $needle = NULL) C:\wamp\www\include\web\sub\betado_stats.php:146
PHP Deprecated:  strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior in C:\wamp\www\include\web\sub\betado_stats.php on line 146
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\include\web\sub\betado_stats.php:0
PHP   2. strpos($haystack = 'Test e-Sports - Pug #2', $needle = NULL) C:\wamp\www\include\web\sub\betado_stats.php:146

$server  = -1;
$servers = array(
    0 => array(
        'Test e-Sports - Pug #1',
        'TeS1'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Test e-Sports - Pug #2',
        'TeS2'
    )
);
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($servers); $i++)
    {
        if(strpos($servers[$i][0], $betados['pug_svname']) !== false) //Aqui
        {
            $server = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece que `$betados` trae valores `null` o `booleanos` y no se puede usar ese tipo de datos como argumento de `strpos()`.

Se podría resolver de varias formas, una puede ser verificando que el valor actual obtenido del array `$betados` sea una cadena, de no ser así, no se hace la comparación:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($servers); $i++) {
    $val = $betados['pug_svname'];
    if(is_string($val) and (strpos($servers[$i][0], $val) !== false)) {
        $server = $i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias :D